# I don't know how to send the session ID after login authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-cookies

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h22L4.png

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 7509;
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8509',
    user: 'root',
    password: '8509',
    database: 'login'
  });

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5502',
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
    name: "session ID",
    secret: "seyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MySQLStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '8509',
        user: 'root',
        password: '8509',
        database: 'login'
      }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 10 * 1000,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
    },
}));

app.post("/login", (req, res) => { 
    id = req.body.id;
    pw = req.body.pw;

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM login_member where id = ?', id,
    function(err, results, fields) {
        dbId = results[0].id;
        dbPw = results[0].password;

        if(id == dbId && pw == dbPw) {

            req.session.save(()=>{
                req.session.user = {
                    id: dbId,
                    pw: dbPw,
                }
            })
            const data = req.session;
            
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Set-Cookie':[`sessionId=test; Domain=http://127.0.0.1:5502/`]
            });

        }else{
            res.redirect("http://127.0.0.1:5502/login_index.html")
        }
    }   
    );
    // connection.end();
    
    console.log(req.session);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(port);
});
```

---

Is there any way to forward session IDs from a backend server to frontend browser cookies with different domains?
If there is no way, what should I do in this situation?

After setting cors and googling for 1 week, session ID was not saved.

I don't know English very well, so I'm using a translator, so please understand that there may be typos. Even if I study coding for the rest of my life, I don't think I can study it